# Mysql install ERROR: Database files are locked. Daemon already running? Warning: Unable to start the server

Tags: software-installation, mysql, sockets

At first I removed previous MySQL installation

```
apt autoremove  mysql-server-8.0
```

MySQL has been removed from services. Then I tried to install new MySQL

```
apt install mysql-server
```

which throws me an error: **ERROR: Database files are locked. Daemon already running? Warning: Unable to start the server.**
Installation ends up but I am not able to start the service cause it throws me an error **Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)**

Can somebody tell me please what it means? What daemon is running if I removed it from system?

Here is the whole installation log from terminal:

```
root@camotestserver:~# apt install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl libencode-locale-perl libevent-core-2.1-7 libfcgi-perl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-template-perl libhttp-date-perl
  libhttp-message-perl libio-html-perl liblwp-mediatypes-perl libmecab2 libtimedate-perl liburi-perl mecab-ipadic mecab-ipadic-utf8 mecab-utils mysql-server-8.0 mysql-server-core-8.0
Suggested packages:
  libdata-dump-perl libipc-sharedcache-perl libwww-perl mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl libencode-locale-perl libevent-core-2.1-7 libfcgi-perl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-template-perl libhttp-date-perl
  libhttp-message-perl libio-html-perl liblwp-mediatypes-perl libmecab2 libtimedate-perl liburi-perl mecab-ipadic mecab-ipadic-utf8 mecab-utils mysql-server mysql-server-8.0
  mysql-server-core-8.0
0 upgraded, 21 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/26.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 182 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package libevent-core-2.1-7:amd64.
(Reading database ... 100373 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-libevent-core-2.1-7_2.1.11-stable-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libevent-core-2.1-7:amd64 (2.1.11-stable-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmecab2:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../01-libmecab2_0.996-10build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmecab2:amd64 (0.996-10build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-core-8.0.
Preparing to unpack .../02-mysql-server-core-8.0_8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-core-8.0 (8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-8.0.
Preparing to unpack .../03-mysql-server-8.0_8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhtml-tagset-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../04-libhtml-tagset-perl_3.20-4_all.deb ...
Unpacking libhtml-tagset-perl (3.20-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liburi-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../05-liburi-perl_1.76-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking liburi-perl (1.76-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhtml-parser-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../06-libhtml-parser-perl_3.72-5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libhtml-parser-perl (3.72-5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcgi-pm-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../07-libcgi-pm-perl_4.46-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libcgi-pm-perl (4.46-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfcgi-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../08-libfcgi-perl_0.79-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfcgi-perl (0.79-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcgi-fast-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../09-libcgi-fast-perl_1%3a2.15-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libcgi-fast-perl (1:2.15-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libencode-locale-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../10-libencode-locale-perl_1.05-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libencode-locale-perl (1.05-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhtml-template-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../11-libhtml-template-perl_2.97-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libhtml-template-perl (2.97-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libtimedate-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../12-libtimedate-perl_2.3200-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libtimedate-perl (2.3200-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhttp-date-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../13-libhttp-date-perl_6.05-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libhttp-date-perl (6.05-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libio-html-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../14-libio-html-perl_1.001-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libio-html-perl (1.001-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liblwp-mediatypes-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../15-liblwp-mediatypes-perl_6.04-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking liblwp-mediatypes-perl (6.04-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhttp-message-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../16-libhttp-message-perl_6.22-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libhttp-message-perl (6.22-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mecab-utils.
Preparing to unpack .../17-mecab-utils_0.996-10build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mecab-utils (0.996-10build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mecab-ipadic.
Preparing to unpack .../18-mecab-ipadic_2.7.0-20070801+main-2.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mecab-ipadic (2.7.0-20070801+main-2.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mecab-ipadic-utf8.
Preparing to unpack .../19-mecab-ipadic-utf8_2.7.0-20070801+main-2.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mecab-ipadic-utf8 (2.7.0-20070801+main-2.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Preparing to unpack .../20-mysql-server_8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up libmecab2:amd64 (0.996-10build1) ...
Setting up libhtml-tagset-perl (3.20-4) ...
Setting up liblwp-mediatypes-perl (6.04-1) ...
Setting up libencode-locale-perl (1.05-1) ...
Setting up mecab-utils (0.996-10build1) ...
Setting up libevent-core-2.1-7:amd64 (2.1.11-stable-1) ...
Setting up libio-html-perl (1.001-1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-core-8.0 (8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up libtimedate-perl (2.3200-1) ...
Setting up libfcgi-perl (0.79-1) ...
Setting up liburi-perl (1.76-2) ...
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
/var/lib/mysql/ibdata1: 44899
ERROR: Database files are locked. Daemon already running?
Warning: Unable to start the server.

Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-05-21 16:39:31 CEST; 9ms ago
    Process: 48199 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 48224 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 48224 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up libhttp-date-perl (6.05-1) ...
Setting up mecab-ipadic (2.7.0-20070801+main-2.1) ...
Compiling IPA dictionary for Mecab.  This takes long time...
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/unk.def ... 40
emitting double-array: 100% |###########################################|
/usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/model.def is not found. skipped.
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Suffix.csv ... 1393
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.proper.csv ... 27328
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.verbal.csv ... 12146
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.adverbal.csv ... 795
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.csv ... 60477
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Others.csv ... 2
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Adnominal.csv ... 135
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.nai.csv ... 42
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Prefix.csv ... 221
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Conjunction.csv ... 171
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Interjection.csv ... 252
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Postp.csv ... 146
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Postp-col.csv ... 91
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Verb.csv ... 130750
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Filler.csv ... 19
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.name.csv ... 34202
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Auxil.csv ... 199
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.place.csv ... 72999
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Adverb.csv ... 3032
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.demonst.csv ... 120
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.others.csv ... 151
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.adjv.csv ... 3328
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.number.csv ... 42
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Symbol.csv ... 208
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Adj.csv ... 27210
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.org.csv ... 16668
emitting double-array: 100% |###########################################|
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/matrix.def ... 1316x1316
emitting matrix      : 100% |###########################################|

done!
update-alternatives: using /var/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic to provide /var/lib/mecab/dic/debian (mecab-dictionary) in auto mode
Setting up mecab-ipadic-utf8 (2.7.0-20070801+main-2.1) ...
Compiling IPA dictionary for Mecab.  This takes long time...
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/unk.def ... 40
emitting double-array: 100% |###########################################|
/usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/model.def is not found. skipped.
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Suffix.csv ... 1393
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.proper.csv ... 27328
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.verbal.csv ... 12146
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.adverbal.csv ... 795
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.csv ... 60477
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Others.csv ... 2
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Adnominal.csv ... 135
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.nai.csv ... 42
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Prefix.csv ... 221
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Conjunction.csv ... 171
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Interjection.csv ... 252
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Postp.csv ... 146
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Postp-col.csv ... 91
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Verb.csv ... 130750
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Filler.csv ... 19
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.name.csv ... 34202
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Auxil.csv ... 199
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.place.csv ... 72999
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Adverb.csv ... 3032
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.demonst.csv ... 120
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.others.csv ... 151
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.adjv.csv ... 3328
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.number.csv ... 42
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Symbol.csv ... 208
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Adj.csv ... 27210
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.org.csv ... 16668
emitting double-array: 100% |###########################################|
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/matrix.def ... 1316x1316
emitting matrix      : 100% |###########################################|

done!
update-alternatives: using /var/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic-utf8 to provide /var/lib/mecab/dic/debian (mecab-dictionary) in auto mode
Setting up libhtml-parser-perl (3.72-5) ...
Setting up libhttp-message-perl (6.22-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-8.0; however:
  Package mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Setting up libcgi-pm-perl (4.46-1) ...
Setting up libhtml-template-perl (2.97-1) ...
Setting up libcgi-fast-perl (1:2.15-1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
W: Operation was interrupted before it could finish
```

Answer (score 6):

Solution for me was in this three commands:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -f
```

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue and after trying the above the installation was stuck at mysqld is running as PID 2802.

I killed the MySQL processes on a different terminal

> pkill mysql

Answer (score 2):

What does `sudo service mysqld status` have to say about this? In any case, `sudo service mysqld stop` might be enough to do the trick.

Comment: STATUS returns Unit mysqld.service could not be found. and STOP Failed to stop mysqld.service: Unit mysqld.service not loaded.

Comment: in my case `mysqld stop` hang forever ..