# MySQL Install error

Tags: server, mysql

I'm a new Linux user.

I've tried to install MySQL, but every time i try to install it, I get the same error.

I executed `sudo apt install mysql-server`, and got:

```
ERROR: Database files are locked. Daemon already running? Warning: Unable to start the server.
```

I was expecting the install to go fine, since every time I've tried to reinstall it, I delete it using `sudo apt autoremove mysql-server`.

I've checked Stack Exchange, and other sites many times, but I've had no luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mysql install ERROR: Database files are locked. Daemon already running? Warning: Unable to start the server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242142/mysql-install-error-database-files-are-locked-daemon-already-running-warning)

Comment: It looks like you have a MySQL Server already running. Check that with: `sudo service mysql status` and edit your question with the result.